# How to use ENV variables in Artisan Commands in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am creating my own artisan command and I want to use ENV variables, but when I use `$_ENV['VariableName']` I get and error.

`local.ERROR: Undefined index: VariableName`

The same code works perfectly in a controller and error as this one is not being generated.

I am creating my commands with `php artisan make:command CommandName`

How can I start using ENV variables there? Thank you! I want to use the variables in a private function which is inside:

`class CommandName extends Command` but outside the `public function handle()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Laravel Helper to access environment variables with something like this:

`env('VariableName')`

you can also specify a default value if the environment variable is not set

`env('VariableName', 'myName')`

[Laravel Docs 5.8 Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-env)

Comment: Thank you, this did the job. I don't know how I missed this in the documentation!

Comment: @Moritz Can you be specific which helper class to be `use`d for allowing the `env` functions to be evaluable in the Artisan Command class files ? Evaluable without specifying any default values... In the doc link you added in answer it just says `Miscellaneous` but never specifically mentions the class to include...

Answer (score 7):

Since the `.env` file is not pushed to the repository, the best approach is to use config files instead. So in the `config` directory, create your custom file for example: `custom.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

return [
   'variable' => env('VARIABLE_NAME', 'DEFAULT_VALUE')
];
```

and in your `.env` you should put:

```
VARIABLE_NAME=something
```

Then to use it you use `config('custom.variable');`

Comment: For anyone's `env` and `config` values returning null inside commands, this is the best approach